# Citrus: should old flower stalks be removed?

Tags: citrus, flowering

A kumquat was bought last winter and then had its fruits removed.

This summer it’s not flowering. I’m wondering what it supposed to happen to the old flower stalks? Should I remove them (because they  are not drying off by themselves) or are they of any use? Do they have to do with the plant not flowering?